# Send ICS file in text message that can be saved

Tags: ios, iphone, icalendar, mms

I am able to create an ICS file containing an event that I can then send via a text message.

The ics file shows up in the text message and opens when you click on it, however, there is no option to save or Add to Calendar.

Is this always the case with a text message or is there anythign I can do in the ICS file that would allow it to be saved to calendar.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Here is sample text in the ICS file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:20201114T170000Z
DTEND:20201115T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
GEO:48.85299;2.36885
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Here is what event looks like when you open it. But no option to save.
[image]